# Adding labels from other views to a UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

Is there anything "wrong" or unhealthy about creating a subview of the view controller's view, assigning it to an IBOutlet UIView * of the viewcontroller, and then placing on that subview a label that is attached to the IBOutlet UILabel * of another subview of the view controller? That is, the label is @property in a custom view class, which also appears on screen, but that custom view is a different view than the view that contains the label from the custom class. Make sense?

It seems to work, but it seems a bit "strange" and I'm wondering if in fact it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how common that is, but I don't think there's anything intrinsically "wrong" with doing it that way.